# Is there any sld styles for OpenStreetMap in ArcGis 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, openstreetmap, sld

I want to display OpenStreetMap any possible way.

1) This map must be similar to the official  OpenStreetMap.

2) Also I must cache data. So I need the WMTS protocol. This is vital.

I can not use Geoserver for my purpose because I can not find sld styles for points.

So I want use ArcGIS Server. But I don't know about sld styles for ArcGIS.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90086/is-there-a-good-qml-or-sld-file-available-for-qgis-openstreetmap-data particularly because I was asking about QGIS - but as QGIS can also use SLD files you may find the discussion helpful.