# Get map from OpenStreetMap and use it as a background with basemap

Tags: openstreetmap, matplotlib-basemap

I want to take a bounding box, use the OpenStreetMap API and get a tile, then use it as a background in basemap. This should be easy, but I haven't been able to figure out the API.

Answer (score 1):

Go to OSM website (http://www.openstreetmap.org), choose a BBOX and select `export`.

When you take data from OSM you'll get just the data. You'll need to import it to your database/QGIS/Geoserver and apply some styles to see the data as seen in OSM map. I know nothing about `matplotlib-basemap`.

To import the data to PostgreSQL you can use `osm2pgsql`:

`osm2pgsql -C 2500 -c -d database_target -U postgre_user -W -s -S ./your_style_file.style your_osm_file.osm`

Your `database_target` must have the GIS extensions.

Getting the same beautiful OSM map appearance is not so easy since there is no official style file to download. You must dig it.

Comment: QGIS has styles for OSM data http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90086/is-there-a-good-qml-or-sld-file-available-for-qgis-openstreetmap-data

Comment: Whoa! Good to know. Can I use them in Geoserver?

Comment: You can export the style from QGIS see http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/style/

Comment: Hi. This isn't quite the information that I'm looking for. I want to do this within Python. I want to use an API to get the data, not a web browser. I want to draw the map using basemap, which is a matplotlib extension. I'm not using PostgreSQL at all.  I'm not using a GIS.

Comment: Well, when you get the OSM data from the API you'll get a `*.osm` file with all data. Beyond this point I can't help you.