# How to apply symbol in group to map attributes in qgis 2 using osm roads as an example

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, symbology, geofabrik

Update: While this question does point to available style guides my question is more how to go about similar operation by yourself and associating your own symbols with osm maps

I downloaded OSM based maps from [GeoFabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) and my question is how to associate the symbols shown in the screen shot with the `fclass` attribute automatically so vectors of `ftype` type "Motorway","Primary" etc all use the appropriate symbol
I tried changing the symbol type to `Categorized` by `ftype` but that still meant I had to manually edit each one and pick the correct symbol.

p.s. are the symbols included in the osm file or are they common to qgis?

[image: Qgis osm road symbols]

Comment: Don't think style files (particularly for QGIS) come with the datasets. This post contains several links to style files made specifically for OSM layers which might help: [Is there a good qml or sld file available for QGIS + Openstreetmap data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90086/is-there-a-good-qml-or-sld-file-available-for-qgis-openstreetmap-data)

Comment: I'm not looking for new styles, just to ensure the 33 symbols shown in the image are associated with the relevant osm road/line without having to manually edit each categorized item individually after categorisation

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/charleyglynn/OSM-Shapefile-QGIS-stylesheets has the work done already

Comment: If you change `Single symbol` to `Categorized`, select your `fclass` field as column then click _Classify_. This should load a symbol for each value in your field. Then click the `Advanced > Match to saved symbols`. This will match the values of the field to the names of the symbols (note that this is case-sensitive).

Comment: Looks like fclass is lowercase

Comment: Run the **Field Calculator**, either update the `fclass` field or create a new string field and use the expression: `title("fclass")`. This will capitalise the values which could be used to match the symbols.

Comment: Thanks, that matched 3, also needed to remember to increase the field length to avoid truncated values

Comment: @Joseph If you post your comments as a question i can mark it as the answer

Comment: I have reopened for @Joseph to post comments as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the features you have in your layer with the symbols shown in your image then you could:

1. Change *Single symbol* to **Categorized**.
2. Ensure the `fclass` field contains values which are title-cased (i.e. values which are lower case but begin with a capitalised letter). If you run the **Field Calculator**, either update the `fclass` field or create a new *string* field and use the expression:

   ```
   title("fclass")
   ```
3. Select your `fclass` field as column then click **Classify**. This should load a symbol for each value in your field. Then from your image, go to

   ```
   Advanced > Match to saved symbols
   ```

   This will match the values of the field to the names of the symbols.