# OpenStreetMap Data Download Stylesheets

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, style

Does anyone have style sheets for the shapefile extracts of OpenStreetMap? The layers which are downloaded `"Lines" "Multilinestrings" "Points" "Multipolygons"` all have attributes associated to them and someone must have dedicated some time towards creating very pretty styles, especially when being open source. [Older posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90086/is-there-a-good-qml-or-sld-file-available-for-qgis-openstreetmap-data) relating to this question direct me to sites with .qml style files although they apply to layers which do not correspond to the more modern shapefiles downloaded from OSM.

[image]

I ended up just styling it under my own steam, check it out!

[image]

Comment: See this post from Anita / Underdark: https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/ From SQLITE we load the data into PostGIS and save the styles in the database - works like a charm.

Comment: What are links to the older posts that you mention?

Comment: Note that the Geofabrik **shapefiles** only offer a subset of the OSM data. Most people prefer the full data from Overpass or Geofabrik **pbf** extracts. The style files from the links are designed for those sources.