# How to get osm tiles in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-3

I am completely lost in the dozen of solution I've found. I would like an easy solution to create an OSM basemap for my different projects with nice styling.

I work directly on my computer, no server or web-based service.

I have set up a postgis database and imported my country's OSM extract (from geofrabick) in it.

And now I would like to know how can I use this in QGis as a basemap with mapnik style or other nice style? I don't need this basemap to be editable nor vertor. Idealy juste a tile raster map.

I know there is somme style sheet around, but if you use large OSM extract rendering if ver very long and not usable to work with you project.

Comment: So, you found some solutions. Which one did you choose and how are you stuck right now?

Comment: In the past I've manage to create a basemap with Tilemill on osx, but now on windows I didn't manage to do the same. It's very complicated for me to do so. But it's the nearest thing to my needs.

Answer (score 3):

I assume an offline vector basemap?

I've made a [style for geofabrik osm extracts (.shp)](https://github.com/MrXsquared/OSM-Geofabrik_Universal-QML-Style). You can use it as template to create your own. Of course it will also work with a PostGIS database as long as it has the same fields and values. But you can also refer to other fields if needed. Created it because I was looking for a vector offline style for OSM as well but could only find these two:

- https://github.com/charleyglynn/OSM-Shapefile-QGIS-stylesheets
- https://github.com/yannos/Beautiful_OSM_in_QGIS

So I used them as inspiration to create my own.

Comment: Thank you. Great work ! I will try it out. I'am a little bit worried if my computer is gonna be ablle to handle the rendering of large area.

Comment: You may find other helpful styles for making a map from your data in this question/answer [ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90086/is-there-a-good-qml-or-sld-file-available-for-qgis-openstreetmap-data  ] - It is worth knowing that QGIS doesn't have to process all the data in one go - you're not heading toward creating raster tiles here, but instead styling up the vector data live (as required). In general terms you make this easier for the computer by being zoomed in enough. If you ask QGIS to show all the data for the whole country I imagine it will fail (zoom in to show a few streets)